# Does using a pointer to access memory in a loop affect program efficiency?

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory

Here is an illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void loop(int *a)
{
    int b = *a;

    for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
    {
        ;
    }
}

void loop_pointer(int *a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *a; ++i)
    {
        ;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // Nothing to see here

    return 0;
}
```

In the `loop` function, the memory is first stored on the stack and then accessed on every iteration. The memory would be cached.

**My question is the following:**
Could the indirection in the `loop_pointer` function result in cache misses? And if so, would a cache miss only occur when the memory is modified(written to) and then accessed(read from) or would it happen on every read?

Comment: compile both and study the output of the compiler. If they are different, measure the executable.

Comment: Yes it could cause cache misses. Depending where `a` is pointing to, and which other areas of memory do you access in the loop (read or write). But the indirect access could also be optimized out.

Comment: cache avoids the memory access regardless whether you use a pointer.

Comment: It's probably more important what you do *within* the loop. If you update some values that `a` could theoretically point to, that could cause frequent reloads of values.

Comment: Compiler optimizations likely play a bigger part... If they ever get smart enough first one might just get tossed out after accessing a

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Comparing assembly code is not a good technique for answering questions like this. It can answer the question only for a specific example and therefore can miss cases. It is better to answer the question based on the programming language specification and the theory and operation of compilers. And even if assembly inspection shows things are fine for one case you are interested in, you would have to repeat the test every time you update the code, adding maintenance burden. Understanding theory and operation is the proper approach.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i slightly disagree. Getting a toy example to play with in compiler explorer can provide surprising insights and is a tool that is often faster to use on your own than finding the correct place in the specification. You are unable to prove your assumptions but it is handy to test them.

Comment: @Mehno: Testing can disprove some hypotheses but is not an appropriate suggestion for people asking general questions. It should not be recommended as an avenue for investigation; posting a comment such as 
463035818_is_not_a_number did suggests that the OP ought to be attempting to learn by that method rather than by asking for information about general theory and operation. Such comments are inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, referring to objects using pointers can impair efficiency. Consider this code:

```
void foo(int *a, int *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *a; ++i)
        *b++ = SomeCalculation(i);
}
```

After `*b++ = SomeCalculation(i);`, has the value of `*a` changed? The compiler cannot know, because the caller might have passed an address for `a` that is somewhere in the memory that `b++` will cover during the loop. Therefore, it must either reload `*a` after each iteration or it must generate extra code to compare `a` and `b` and the value of `*a` before the loop. (If that run-time test determines `*b++` never updates the memory of `a`, it can branch to a loop like your first example, where `*a` is loaded once and cached. Otherwise, it must use branch to another loop that accounts for `*a` changing.)

C provides the `restrict` qualifier to tell the compiler that something like this will not happen. In this code:

```
void foo(int * restrict a, int *b)
{
    …
}
```

the compiler may assume that `*a` never changes while `foo` is executing except through `a`. (`restrict` does allow this change to be indirect; if you have `int *c = a;` inside `foo`, then changing `*a` via `*c` is allowed with `restrict`, because the compiler can see `c` derives from `a` inside `foo`, but changing `*a` via `b` would violate the `restrict`.)

Similarly, one might wish to add `restrict` to the `b` parameter to tell the compiler that the things `b` points to are not affected by changes via other points.

Comment: I would also add that this does not mean that the former approach is better. If the compiler is able to prove that the loop bode does not modify the memory pointed to it is able to optimze the indirection away. See: https://godbolt.org/z/GE5q4Knhh

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me correctly...
When compiled, both of your 'for' loop conditions ('i<b' and 'i<*a') will be computed once and assigned to a stack address.
Unless 'a' is declared as 'volatile', 'a' will not be re-computed on each 'for' iteration.
Try compiling your code (removing #include<stdio.h>") with -S and take a look at the asm code.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I look at the assembly, you are correct. The compiler managed to optimize the code.